# DB2 SQL: Grouping records with same id in result?

Tags: sql, db2

if I have a table with 2 columns

```
text | id
---------
aaa  |  1
bbb  |  1
eee  |  1
mmm  |  2
zzz  |  2
...
```

Is it possible to write a query which groups by id and outputs the following result:

```
id | text
------------------
 1 | aaa, bbb, eee
 2 | mmm, zzz
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  ID, 
        SUBSTR(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(CONCAT( ', ',text))) as VARCHAR(1024)), 3)
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `listagg` function in DB2:

```
select id, listagg(text, ', ') as text
from t
group by id
```

If you want them ordered alphabetically:

```
select id, listagg(text, ', ') within group (order by text) as text
from t
group by id
```

Comment: Do I need to some special authorization in order to execute listagg? I am using DB2 9.7 but I get an error -440 when trying to use "listagg"?

Comment: @user1613270 . . . Listagg is fully supported in DB2 9.7 . . . http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0058709.html.